# Upgrading Rails app from 2 to 5 - offloading model logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My team and I are in currently on a very old version of Rails 2 and we want to upgrade to the latest and greatest. To that end, we started with creating a brand new app on Rails 5 as a private API-only app to communicate with our old app (think of it as like a microservice) to begin the slow upgrade process - any new feature we had, we would try to route it to the Rails 5 app, do its processing, and then send it back over to the old app. If we needed models, like a User, we would define it again in our new app, as well as keeping the old User model in the old app. Over time, we will have more and more requests redirected and being processed in Rails 5, with the end goal of having all our business logic in Rails 5 and deprecating our Rails 2 app completely. I've read that it's advised to upgrade from 2 to 3, 3 to 4, and finally 4 to 5, but given that we are three major versions behind, we thought it'd be "easier" to circumvent that by creating a brand new app.

Our plan was to slowly move logic/models over from the old app to the new app, but we quickly ran into an issue. If we had logic that involved `User` model’s associations, we would also need to replicate the associations into the new app. If the associated model also had its own associations, we would also have to duplicate that over. It's becoming a never-ending nightmare of having to duplicate associations of associations whenever we considered having a new feature in our new app, making our initial approach of slowly upgrading portions of the app look very grim. I was wondering if anyone else has had a similar experience trying to upgrade the app in this way? Any advice would be great on how we should be approaching this. It doesn't have to be advice that conforms to our chosen approach.

Comment: I'd make a 1on1 copy of the old version and new version, including all models and associations. It's tempting to only add just the things you care about for now as you move over individual endpoints, but as you can see, it becomes a rats nest of interdependencies. Since you're moving everything over to the new app anyway, it won't be wasted work. My vote is for building a shadow app in Rails 5, and then using a load balance to switch individual endpoints from the Rails 2 app to the Rails 5 app. Perhaps by adding a version parameter in the URL, and then keeping the two versions in parity.

Comment: You could try using a gem with your models, that way, you can share the same code with both apps and adapt whatever you need on each of them. You'll have to add code for each version, but most functionality could be shared and you don't have to replicate all the association, just move things from rails2app to the gem and rails5app will have access.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. @billy-kimble Your (first) suggestion is specifically one that we wanted to avoid doing, but I guess with the way we have approached it so far, we don't really have much of a choice and we'll continue down this route. I'll do some research about the shadow app approach. if anymore ideas/insight come to mind, they are more than welcomed! :) Thanks again